# Calling a function after a long job (callback)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have function like this:

```
function update_List(){
            LIST=[];
            $.each(feed_urls,function(index,value){
                $.getJSON(value, function(data) {
                    $.each(data.feed.entry,function(i,val){
                           LIST.push(val.content.src);
                    });
                });
            });
          some_function();
        }
```

The problem is that `some_function();` gets called before `LIST` gets fully updated .

How can I resolve this ?

I tried using custom events , and I also looked up some things on callback , but nothing has really helped .

EDIT: I want `some_function()` to be called only after all the `getJSON` calls have completed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to call the function after all Ajax calls are completed, you should use [*deferred objects*](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
function update_List(){
    LIST=[];
    var deferreds = [];
    $.each(feed_urls,function(index,value){
        deferreds.push($.getJSON(value, function(data) {
            $.each(data.feed.entry,function(i,val){
                LIST.push(val.content.src);
            });
        }));
    });
    $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(some_function);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to call some_function() inside the getJSON, so that it's done only after the asynchronous call is completed.

```
function update_List(){
            LIST=[];
            $.each(feed_urls,function(index,value){
                $.getJSON(value, function(data) {
                    $.each(data.feed.entry,function(i,val){
                           LIST.push(val.content.src);
                    });
                    some_function();
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Note that he wants call `some_function` after all `getJSON` calls are completed.

Comment: This works , But it wastes a lot of time trying to process when `LIST`  is not ready !

Answer (score 1):

`some_function();` will never wait as `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous operation.

```
function isEveryoneDone(theList){
  var isDone = false;
  for(var jsonStatus = 0; jsonStatus< theList.length;jsonStatus++){
    if(theList[jsonStatus]){
     isDone &=theList[jsonStatus].isDone;
     if(!isDone){ break;}
    }else{
     break;
    }
  }
  return isDone;
}
function update_List(){
            LIST=new Array(feed_urls.length);
            $.each(feed_urls,function(index,value){
                $.getJSON(value, function(data) {
                    $.each(data.feed.entry,function(i,val){
                           LIST.push({"isDone":true,"src":val.content.src});
                           if(isEveryoneDone(LIST)){
                             doSomething();
                           }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: `$.each` is not asynchronous.